# How to decode a packet in PyShark as decode_as

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, tshark, pyshark

In Wireshark GUI, we can decode a UPD packet as RTP, and the same can be done in tshark using  `d <layer type>==<selector>,<decode-as protocol>`

How can i do the same in PyShark ?
I tried doing the following

```
import pyshark

cap = pyshark.FileCapture("Test.pcap", display filter='udp', decode_as='rtp')
for pkt in cap:
   print(pkt)
```

But it shows the following error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

decode_as argument should be a dict and not str
Example:

```
decode_as={'udp.port==1234':'rtp'}
```